# In Mapbox.js why doesn't onEachFeature work any more?

Tags: javascript

In older versions of mapbox.js you can do something like this:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(popupHtml);
    console.log(layer);
}
```

when calling `L.geoJson` to wire in a popup when you click on a feature in the layer (in this case a polygon shape). However, it seems that in everything AFTER 3.0.0, this no longer works. If I log out the layer to the console, I can see that the popup has been set and it says the event handlers are all wired in. However, clicking on the shapes does nothing.

According to the docs, the method still exists and it doesn't say you need to do anything else to get it to work. So why aren't the popups firing (or indeed ANY of the layer events)?

I must be missing something, either the feature just doesn't work any more and they never updated the docs, or there's an extra step that needs to happen for the events to work. It's ANY events wired into the layers that no longer work. For example, go to: https://jsfiddle.net/oafhj4bt/1/ and update the mapbox.js reference to the latest version and you'll see all of the events based code no longer fires.

Any pointers greatly appreciated on this one, as I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY got to the bottom of this. It was caused by a purge CSS task in the front end build that was stripping out classes that mapbox needs to work properly and a mismatch in the mapbox CSS files being used.

Whitelisting the mapbox CSS and updating the mapbox CSS file meant the events fired again. Without the missing CSS, pointer-evets were set to none, causing no events to actually fire!